# Spark and Postgres - How to read big tables in a partitioned way?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I'm looking for suggestions to approach this problem:

- parallel queries using JDBC driver
- big (in rows) Postgres table
- there is no numeric column to be used as `partitionColumn`

I would like to read this big table using multiple parallel queries, but there is no evident numeric column to partition the table. I thought about the physical location of the data using CTID, but I'm not sure if I should follow this path.

Comment: CTID can change at any point in time and you need CHECK constraint in order to benefit from partitions in Postgres, so it would not work. You just need to look at the queries and see if any of the WHERE conditions can be used as partition column. It doesn't have to be numeric, it could be "country", "color" or whatever.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński, in the case of non-numeric columns, how would I fill the other options like `upperBound` and `lowerBound`? Would it make sense to fill in with categorical values?

Comment: What do you mean by those bounds? You don't need to to use range for partitioning, it can be anything that is constant for the row (or you move data between partitions if you change said value). So taking from doumentation, this constraint will work just fine: `CHECK ( county IN ( 'Oxfordshire', 'Buckinghamshire', 'Warwickshire' ))`. Of course date range is the most obvious one, assuming you could use it (but from what you say you can't): `CHECK ( logdate >= DATE '2007-12-01' AND logdate < DATE '2008-01-01' )`

Comment: Now I get it - those are Spark specific values. Sorry, I don't know how to partition such table with this limitation. :(

Comment: Thank you anyway, @ŁukaszKamiński. Those are Spark specific thing, but the discussion helped. It seems that the option `predicates` is closer to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The [spark-postgres](https://github.com/EDS-APHP/spark-postgres) library provides several functions to read/load postgres data. It uses the COPY statement under the hood. As a result it can handle large postgres tables.